# Cant get php exec to work

Tags: php, exec

I've been fighting with this for a few hours now, and I can't seem to work it out.
tried exec(), shell_exec(), and system(). Nothing works.
I have this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/shell/send.php >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/shell/paging.log &");
```

send.php simply has:

```
echo 'works';
```

But nothing shows up in the log. I've googled and read stuff on here, but I can't find anything to help.

I'm running php v.5.3.8.
safe mode is on
I'm pretty sure that is the path to php, but can't really find out how to find it, so I'm going on phpinfo().

exec('whoami'); does nothing. Is it suppose to show in the browser? or email you something?
any ideas?

Comment: try /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/file.php (the -f flag)

Comment: nothing still. just ssh'd to the server, that is the correct path to php. Maybe safe mode has something to do with it?

Comment: safe mode might be affecting your call: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP Manual for `exec` function:

> When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed
>   to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir

Also, be aware that the web server user must have permission to write in the log file.

EDIT: To **turn safe mode off**, check not only **php.ini** file but also virtual hosts specific configurations in your web server, whether it is Apache, NginX or other. If you use Plesk, look in vhosts for httpd.include, and make sure that safe_mode is set to off there as well.

Comment: Updated my answer. I've read the whole page for exec, shell_exec and system. Nothing works.

Comment: So, first, connect using SSH and run the command `/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/shell/send.php` and tell us the output.

Comment: Two more questions for you: 1) Is safe mode turned on or off? 2) Does send.php have the PHP opening and closing tags? I mean `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: Also, you should try `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` just to see a simple "exec" functioning.

Comment: L. Bruni read OP. echoing whoami does nothing from a browser.works from the command line. outputs: Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater Unknown on line 1. leaving the log part out prints 'works'. and putting the log part in adds it to the log file just fine.

Comment: @David: I asked about `whoami` because OP does not mention `echo`. Anyway, it seems we have either a **safe mode** issue or a **file permission** issue, or both. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Just set php safe_mode to off in php.ini. Master shows off, local still shows on. ah, yes I echoed it. file permissions are set to 777 across the board. Still nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4309/discussion-between-david-and-j-bruni)

Answer (score 1):

```
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute 
> a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back
> without any interference, use the passthru() function. To get the output
> of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.
```

I am not looking for output, and the last two arguments of exec() are optional. I my case what I really need is to be able to open a folder on the desktop. This exact syntax worked very well in MAMP_PRO_1.9.6, but no longer works in MAMP_PRO_2.0.5 (it's broken)

```
<?php
    exec("open /path/to/any/folder");   //  BROKEN in Mamp Pro 2.0.5
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output, you need to pass a second parameter, or you can get the last line of output by echo'ing it.

From the PHP manual:

`string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`

**Return Values:**

*The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.
To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.*