# How to use php exec or shee_exec to run a script I wrote

Tags: php, shell, exec

I have a script that resizes called "resize"
Here is the script:

```
<?
echo exec('resize');
?>
```

This page is located in my /var/www/site/resize.php
the resize command is located in /bin/resize and it is owned by root with permission mod 777
However, the command is not being executed. Please let me know what I need.

I have also tried using the absolute path to the resize script

```
    echo exec('/bin/resize');
```

Comment: Did you enable error_reporting. What does the webservers error.log say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant get php exec to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785409/cant-get-php-exec-to-work) -- or see [php exec does not work reasons](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20exec%20does%20not%20work%20reasons) if you got more concrete clues.

Comment: @mario I was going to, but i dont know the proper syntax and php.net is down right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the backtick operator ` or shell_exec()

Comment: that was it. shell_exec did it. What is backtick

Comment: It is the same thing as shell_exe(); For example: `\`ls -lah`\` See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux:

```
exec('php -q /bin/resize.php');
```