# php function execute - connection between php and C++ serverbased

Tags: php, c++

I am currently working on a project, where I have to build a webpage, where I get some Data from the User and than convert that to a tree.

To make it run faster, I call a selfwrote C++ programm from php, where I sent all the needed Informations with JSON.

On Laptop I have Apache installed and on the localhost everything is working fine.

Now I moved all the files on the server and it doesn't work anymore. 
I think it has to do something with the connection between php and the C++ execute.

Has someone an Idea how I can test this clearly, to get where the mistake is? Because the function to call the C++ program seems to be enabled on the server.

The code where I call the C++ programm:

```
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
$val = "";
if ($mode == "f") {
 $sequenceList = $_POST['sequenceList'];
 $family = $_POST['family'];

 if ($sequenceList == "") {
  echo "error - no Sequences Added";
 } else if ($family == "") {
  echo "error - no Family Added";
 } else {
  exec("TreeDom.exe {$mode} {$sequenceList} {$family}", $output;

  foreach($output as $line) {
   $val=$line;
  }

  echo $val;
 } 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code for the communication between your two programs.

Comment: Sorry, I added it now! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is in a shared hosting (generic low-cost domain solution), the `exec` function may not work due to PHP safe mode. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785409/cant-get-php-exec-to-work) for more insights.

It can be also a permission issue.